# SQL Server : double hop linked server running SELECT Query

Tags: sql-server, select, linked-server

I'm quite new to SQL Server. I have a question: I have 3 SQL servers, 2 on domain Domain1 and 1 on Domain2.

- SQL Server 1 & 2 are on Domain1
- SQL Server_3 is on Domain2.
- SQL Server_1 - linked to SQL Server_2 and SQL Server 2 is linked to SQL Server 3.

My Windows authentication is Admin on all Windows servers and SQL Servers across all 3 servers. I'm trying to run a `SELECT` query on `SQLServer_1` to retrieve data from `SQLServer_3` using `SQLServer_2` as a middle jump point (connecting directly between `SQLServer_1` and `SQLServer_3` unfortunately is out of options)

I've tried running these query on `SQLServer_1` :

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM [SQLServer_2].[SQLServer_3].[DBName_1].[Table_Name1]
```

But I get this error:

> The object name 'SQLServer_2.SQLServer_3.DBName_1.Table_Name1' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM [SQLServer_3].[DBName_1].[Table_Name1]
```

results in:

> Could not find server 'SQLServer_3' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

So both didn't work.

Please HELP. Is it even possible?

Comment: Perhaps use OPENQUERY on the second server to run a query on the third? e.g. on server 1 `select * from openquery(server2, 'select * from server3.database.schema.table;');` Alternatively, you might consider executing a stored procedure on server2 (that connects to server3) from server1.

Comment: Thank you !!!! man AWESOME it worked :))) whooohoooo

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you ZLK 23. He's suggestion worked. I dont know how to post it
>   as an answer if any one does please help me out.

Perhaps use `OPENQUERY` on the second server to run a query on the third? e.g. on server 1 select * from openquery(server2, 'select * from server3.database.schema.table;'); Alternatively, you might consider executing a stored procedure on server2 (that connects to server3) from server1. – ZLK 23 hours ago

> I ran this query from SQLServer_1. In my understanding it runs query
>   SELECT on SQLServer_2 the SELECT QUERY in the second parameter and
>   retrieves the results back. Which has worked perfect for me.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQLSERVER_2,'SELECT * FROM 'SQLSERVER_3.DBNAME.TABLENAME')
```

Thank you again.